# Hiding a constructor behind a static creator method?

Tags: java

I've recently discovered an interesting way to create a new instance of an object in [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html#create()) and [Project Lombok](http://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html): Hide a constructor behind a static creator method. This means that instead of doing `new HashBiMap()`, you do `HashBiMap.create()`.

My question is why? What advantage do you have of hiding the constructor? To me I see absolutely no advantage of doing this, and it seems to break basic object creation principles. Since the beggining you create an object with `new Object()`, not some `Object.createMe()` method. This almost seems like creating a method for the sake of creating a method.

What do you gain from doing this?

Comment: Note that you'll get warnings using the raw `new HashBiMap()`, where you won't using `HashBiMap.create()`. This is the primary reason Guava uses this pattern, as I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why you might prefer a static factory method instead of a public constructor. You can read Item 1 in [Effective Java, Second Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) for a longer discussion.

1. It allows the type of the object returned by the method to be different than the type of the class that contains the method. In fact, the type returned can depend on the parameters. For example, `EnumSet.of(E)` will return a different type if the emum type has very few elements vs if the enum type has many elements (*Edit:* in this particular case, improving performance for the common case where the enum doesn't have many elements)
2. It allows caching. For instance, `Integer.valueOf(x)` will, by default, return the same object instance if called multiple times with the same value `x`, if `x` is between -128 and 127.
3. It allows you to have named constructors (which can be useful if your class needs many constructors). See, for example, the methods in `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.
4. It allows you to create an API that is conceptually simple but actually very powerful. For instance, the static methods in `Collections` hides many types. Instead of having a `Collections` class with many static methods, they could have created many public classes, but that would have been harder for someone new to the language to understand or remember.
5. For generic types, it can limit how much typing you need to do. For example, instead of typing `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>()` in Guava you can do `List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList()` (the `newArrayList` method is a generic method, and the type of the generic type is inferred).

For `HashBiMap`, the last reason is the most likely.

Comment: Hmm, looks like these are all very minor and edge-case advantages.  Since static creators/factories fly in the face of OOP, the rampant use of this pattern doesn't seem justified.

Comment: @ScottBiggs I disagree that static creational methods "fly in the face of OOP." Note that these reasons all come from _Effective Java, Second Edition_ which is the definitive "best practices" guide for Java, and all of the examples I gave are from the JDK.

Comment: Feel free to disagree.  Even topics written in books can defy OOP practices.  Instead of appealing to authority (a single book), I will appeal to your sense of reason: because static factories bypass the explicit creation of objects (constructors), don't they go against the idea of objects?  Factories are tantamount to using global variables and functions--both practices that OOP was trying to prevent.

Comment: @ScottBiggs the central point of OO is to use objects to encapsulate data and behavior. I don't see how using a static method instead of a constructor to create objects in Java goes against that idea, but if you do feel free to add your own answer to this question. As for _Effective Java_, the author,  Joshua Bloch, led the design and implementation of the Java collections framework; I think we can let the SO voters decide if his opinions (summarized above) are worthwhile.

Answer (score 7):

This is usually done because the class actually instantiated by the `create()` method might be different than the type upon which you are invoking the method.  i.e. a factory pattern where the `create()` method returns a specific subclass that is appropriate given the current context.   (For example, returning one instance when the currrent environment is Windows, and another when it is Linux).

Comment: Shouldn't that be for special cases only? Because HashBiMap in Guava doesn't do any special caching, just returning a new instance. And you can't override it (or TMK mock it) because its static. http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java#57

Comment: @TheLQ, I wasn't speaking about the library specifically.  Just in general terms about what a `create()` factory method could be used for.  Also, what does overriding it have to do with anything?  If you're suggesting that it's difficult to unit-test this pattern, I completely agree.

Comment: @Kirk I was trying to be more general. Should you use this pattern on everything, or only when absolutely needed to return specific implementations?

Comment: @TheLQ, oh, definitely do *not* use this for everything.  Nothing wrong with the **new** operator.  Just keep this in mind as a nice tool to solve certain problems.

Comment: There is no pattern that should be used for everything.

Comment: You can't mock a constructor, either (in other words, from a mocking standpoint, a static factory method is not any less flexible than a public constructor)

Answer (score 6):

Unlike constructors, static methods can have method names. Here's a recent class I wrote where this was useful:

```
/**
 * A number range that can be min-constrained, max-constrained, 
 * both-constrained or unconstrained.
 */

public class Range {
  private final long min;
  private final long max;
  private final boolean hasMin;
  private final boolean hasMax;

  private Range(long min, long max, boolean hasMin, boolean hasMax) {
    // ... (private constructor that just assigns attributes)
  }

  // Static factory methods

  public static Range atLeast (long min) {
    return new Range(min, 0, true, false);
  }

  public static Range atMost (long max) {
    return new Range(0, max, false, true);
  }

  public static Range between (long min, long max) {
    return new Range(min, max, true, true);
  }

  public static Range unconstrained () {
    return new Range (0, 0, false, false);
  }
}
```

You couldn't do this using just constructors, as `atLeast` and `atMost` would have the exact same signature (they both take one long).

Answer (score 3):

This is called a Factory method pattern. Where the factory lies within the class itself. [Wikipedia describes it pretty well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) but here are a few snippets.

> Factory methods are common in toolkits and frameworks where library code needs to create objects of types which may be subclassed by applications using the framework.
>
> Parallel class hierarchies often require objects from one hierarchy to be able to create appropriate objects from another.

Comment: The factory pattern works well in things like `BorderFactory`, but I'm not understanding why you would do the factory pattern and your class in one class. What are you gaining by doing this?

Comment: See: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.java#57 I'm curious to why would use this pattern when your accomplishing the same thing but with more code.

Comment: I don't believe this is true. A factory method will be an instance method. Swing uses the pattern a fair amount.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be possible for `SomeClass.create()` to pull an instance from a cache.  `new SomeClass()` won't do that without some shenanigans.

It would be also be possible for `create()` to return any number of implementations of `SomeClass`.  Basically, a Factory type of dealio.

Answer (score 0):

Although not applicable to this particular code example, the practice of hiding the constructor behind a static method is [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java). This is used when you want to ensure that a single instance of the class is created and used throughout.

Comment: Thats a bit of a stretch of what I was getting at, but I guess for a single constructor hiding method you could do this.

Comment: Even without the singleton pattern, this way of object creation does come in handy if you want the object to be instantiated in a particular way alone for e.g.: a hash-map with an optimized initial size instead of relying on the API user to provide it for you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to use this factory method pattern, but one major reason Guava uses it is that it lets you avoid using type parameters twice when creating a new instance. Compare:

```
HashBiMap<Foo, Bar> bimap = new HashBiMap<Foo, Bar>();

HashBiMap<Foo, Bar> bimap = HashBiMap.create();
```

Guava also makes good use of the fact that factory methods can have useful names, unlike constructors. Consider `ImmutableList.of`, `ImmutableList.copyOf`, `Lists.newArrayListWithExpectedSize`, etc.

It also takes advantage of the fact that factory methods don't necessarily have to create a new object. For instance, `ImmutableList.copyOf`, when given an argument that is itself an `ImmutableList`, will just return that argument rather than doing any actual copying.

Finally, `ImmutableList`'s factory methods return (non-public) subclasses of `ImmutableList` such as `EmptyImmutableList`, `SingletonImmutableList` and `RegularImmutableList` depending on the arguments.

None of these things are possible with constructors.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `HashBiMap<Foo, Bar> bimap = new HashBiMap()` would work just fine since the `<Foo, Bar>` is implied.

Comment: It will _work_, yes, but it'll also generate warnings for use of the raw type instead of the parameterized type... you shouldn't do it. Static methods can infer the type parameters and do the same thing without warnings.

Comment: I should also note that it's incorrect to say that the `<Foo, Bar>` is implied. It's not. You're just using the raw type, pre-generics style. In JDK7, you'll be able to use the diamond operator, like this `Map<Foo, Bar> map = new HashMap<>()`, which does infer the types similar to the way static methods do.

Answer (score 0):

i got very interesting reason to hide constructor check it and please let me know if there is any other alternative to achieve this

```
enter code here

Class A
 {
   String val;
    protected A( )
     {
     }
    protected A(String val)
     {
       this.val=val;
     }
   protected void setVal( String val)
    {
       this.val=val;
    } 
   public String getVal()
    {
      return val;
    }    
}
class B extends A
  {
     B()
     {
       super();
     }     
    public val setVal(String val)
    {
      super.val=val;    
    }
} 
class C extends A
{
    C(String val)
    {
      super(val);
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have a factory method in there ... and to be honest, I don't know where this code should be a good example of hiding the constructor. So you should explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

## Some main reasons

- Primarily it gives you the power to instantiate a different (sub) class
- Possibility to return `null`
- It enables you to return an already existing object