# In Java it seems Public constructors are always a bad coding practice

Tags: java, coding-style

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Consider providing static factory methods insteads of constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046877/consider-providing-static-factory-methods-insteads-of-constructors)

This maybe a controversial question and may not be suited for this forum (so I will not be insulted if you choose to close this question).

It seems given the current capabilities of Java there is no reason to make constructors `public` ... **ever**. Friendly, `private`, `protected` are OK but `public` no.

It seems that its almost always a better idea to provide a `public static` method for creating objects. Every Java Bean serialization technology (JAXB, Jackson, Spring etc...) can call a protected or private no-arg constructor.

My questions are:

- I have never seen this practice decreed or written down anywhere? Maybe Bloch mentions it but I don't own is book.
- Is there a use case other than perhaps not being super DRY that I missed?

**EDIT: I explain why static methods are better.**

.1. For one you get better type inference. For example See Guava's http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained

.2. As a designer of the class you can later change what is returned with a static method.

.3. Dealing with constructor inheritance is painful especially if you have to pre-calculate something.
.4. More reasons here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852556/318174

I should have posted that this is for public API like code. I frequently violate all sorts of rules (like using direct field access) for Unit Testing, convenience, and cause I'm lazy.  So when I meant **ever**, I meant your releasing it into the wild.

Comment: `Maybe Bloch mentions it but I don't own is book.` -> You always have internet, to read it online. And that is the best resource you can have to understand this aspect.

Comment: @RohitJain I have read snippets online in various articles and coworks  have had the book. I had no idea its entirety is online. I'll have to google for it.

Comment: Just top mention, if you are considering `static factory`, then private constructors are ok. no public, no protected. You don't want to instantiate this class from outside right? Not even from subclasses.

Comment: @AdamGent.. See the post I have given. There I have provided with the link for the book, and also the pros and cons of it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with creating an object using its public constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If following is how the method looks

```
public class MyClass {

    private MyClass() { }

    public static MyClass getInstance() {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}
```

then would prefer to have a public no-arg constructor.

If I have to call some method like that, it will make me feel that it is doing something to construct the object but in reality it isn't.

I don't think there is any point in having a method that doesn't do anything but invoke the constructor itself.

Comment: +1 Now thats a good reason. But the only issue is that you now have to make either the class final or worry about people subclassing (if thats your concern.)

Comment: @BheshGurung. There is also, various other points, that you can consider that can favour the use of `static factories`.

Comment: For e.g. a static factory can return an instance of any subtype of the class. You can have it in another class (which is preferable, to have factory in other class rather than inside a class), which will instantiate the class for you.

Comment: @RohitJain: I like having them, it's just an example where I would prefer not to have one.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Yeah then in that case, its perfectly fine. +1

Answer (score 5):

In short, static factories are cool and they have their uses, but some APIs fall into the trap of using them everywhere even when they don't add value and just add complexity.

One example of where static factory works well in Java is EnumSet which has a number of named builders could not be naturally implemented as overloaded constructors.

e.g. these don't do the same thing even though they have the same arguments.

```
EnumSet.of(E1, E3);
EnumSet.range(E1, E3);
```

Also EnumSet returns two different implementations based on the number of elements in the enum.

```
    if (universe.length <= 64)
        return new RegularEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
    else
        return new JumboEnumSet<>(elementType, universe);
```

Unfortunately EnumMap doesn't do similarly and so there is only one implementation.

---

> .1. For one you get better type inference. For example See Guava's

So Guava has methods like

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = Lists.newArrayList();
Map<KeyType, LongishValueType> map = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
```

which in Java 7 is just

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<KeyType, LongishValueType> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

which is shorter, you don't need to learn any new methods and Java 6 you could do the following if you didn't need double checking of types.

```
List<TypeThatsTooLongForItsOwnGood> list = new ArrayList();
Map<KeyType, LongishValueType> map = new LinkedHashMap();
```

In Guava you have

```
Set<Type> copySet = Sets.newHashSet(elements);
List<String> theseElements = Lists.newArrayList("alpha", "beta", "gamma");
```

where as the built-in methods are

```
Set<Type> copySet = new HashSet<String>(elements);
List<String> theseElements = Arrays.asList("alpha", "beta", "gamma");
```

If you drop the `<String>` from HashSet you lose type safety but given most decent IDE will auto-complete this code for you, you won't actually be saving any typing.

> .2. As a designer of the class you can later change what is returned with a static method.

I would say YAGNI, and it is very difficult in practice to significantly change the implementation transparently. It is highly unlikely you can drop in a replacement with full backward compatibility without having to rebuild or retest your code.

> .3. Dealing with constructor inheritance is painful especially if you have to pre-calculate something.

This is true, but rare. For this situation I usually have a builder class for complex construction and a factor method alone wouldn't solve the problem.

---

Its worth considering that most classes in the Java Libraries use constructors rather than static factories.  The only classes I can think of where constructors were used but later changed to use static factories where possible was the auto-boxing wrapper classes. The  complexity of knowing which factory method to call is hidden by the language.

> It seems given the current capabilities of Java there is no reason to make constructors public ... ever. Friendly, private, protected are OK but public no.

Just because you can do something doesn't make it good idea.

For example, you can make all your classes, methods and variables 1 or 2 characters long  (you never need to use a name 3 letters or longer and some people believe this is better some how) but that does not make it is good idea.

BTW if you have looks at common UNIX commands, many are two characters long. ;)

> It seems that its almost always a better idea to provide a public static method for creating objects.

Unless you prefer simplicity and not making your code needlessly complicated.

> I have never seen this practice decreed or written down anywhere?

Neither have I. Possibly because its not a good idea. IMHO.

> Is there a use case other than perhaps not being super DRY that I missed?

You haven't stated a good reason to do it, that's reason enough not to do it for me. ;)

Comment: +1 For Just because you can do something doesn't make it good idea.

Comment: Did you mean `does not` in your 2nd paragraph 2nd last line?

Comment: @PeterLawrey. Cheers :) +1 Like the answer though. But I think there are some reasons why we can use static factories, and they are considered a boon than a constructor. You can add them too.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I find your answer a little insulting. People rarely make their classes two letters long but `public` constructors are common practice so its not the same. And most of Guava uses static factories... they must be wrong right?

Comment: For KDB it is recommended practice and for UNIX commands its common so not always considered a strange idea. Its hard to argue with merely asserting that ` there is no reason to make constructors public` without giving any reason or logic behind it.

Comment: If prefer code to be have a minimum of assumptions about what it is doing and generally shorter where possible.  Guava makes programming more magical and often more complex (partly due to Java's lack of support for closures)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think I didn't make it clear enough that this was for public facing code (aka a library). Its not like I'll never make a public constructor again and I do frequently use field access instead of getters (because I'm lazy). Perhaps I should remove the word *ever*.

Comment: @AdamGent I would using the wording, seriously consider whether a  factory is better than a constructor for a public API. If it is, use it, if not use the constructor because its simpler. Where factories are particularly useful is when you use instance factories like JDBC, JMS, SAX do.

Comment: *Its worth considering that most classes in the Java Libraries use constructors rather than static factories.* -- Most of `javax` uses static factory methods (ie JAXB). Partly to support the service provider pattern. It is mainly the JDK where this is not the case.

Comment: Perhaps its a matter of taste but JAXB is one of the most cumbersome libraries in the Java universe and one of the slowest as a result, ;)

Comment: I personally find it revealing that Josh Bloch wrote most of the collections APIs using public constructors -- and now recommends that you _not_ follow that example, and use factories.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Interesting point, I wonder if the reasons were addressed in Java 7.

Comment: I can certainly see it as the best they could do while maintaining backwards compatibility.  (That said, there are other things about the Collections API that go contrary to EJ items, but that couldn't be changed while staying backwards-compatible -- see e.g. Item 17.)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Come on JAXB isn't that slow for XML databinding. I suppose your cumbersome remark meaning you can accidentally plugin in the wrong XML parser. Regardless you can use a different implementation like MOXy (thanks to static factory service provider pattern :) ). Also one of my favorite hackers Kohsuke co-wrote it... you know the guy who wrote Jenkins.

Comment: @AdamGent It depends on your requirements. JAXB is the right answer if it suits your needs. If want a low GC solution, it's not for you ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah but it is that because of the static factories? (I'm actually asking as in I'm not sure).

Comment: @AdamGent I admit I am not sure what the root cause it, but the implementations I have seen create a surprising amount of garbage even compared with say Java Serialization which I also consider heavy weight. It is possible to write an XML parser and binder which can process GB of data without creating any garbage.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think so. Constructors are needed to create objects. Constructors *guarantee* that object indeed created that is not correct for factory method that can return null.

The choice between constructors or factory methods depends on concrete use case. Sometimes constructor is better, sometimes factory methods have advantages.

I'd rather say that having static factory method into the class itself is bad practice in most cases. IMHO separation of class itself and its factory is preferable solution.

I do not think that all frameworks support factory methods. Spring and JAXB indeed support but for example `HttpServlet`, `HttpFilter`, EJB, Applet etc must have public default constructor. Even in case of spring usage of beans that have constructor is more convenient than beans that require factory method for their instanciation.

Comment: +1 for the 3rd paragraph. Indeed that is something one should follow. rather than having them in the class itself. :)

Comment: @AlexR almost every technology can call protected or private constructors. Hibernate in fact just ignores them altogether and will even set `final` variables (scary).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one use case for public constructors.  If you use an annotation processing framework, you will need to implement a `Processor`.  The compiler will use reflection to create an instance of your Processor.  In order for the system to work, your implementation class should be public, not generic, and have a public no-args constructor.

So public constructors are probably useful for frameworks that use reflection.

Comment: This is not true. Through reflection you can get access to protected and private methods (although supposedly I guess the security manager could get mad). JAXB, Jackson, etc... use reflection.

Comment: @AdamGent Yes you could get access to protected and private methods, but if the program that you are working with does not do that, then you need a public constructor.

Comment: I just haven't seen a library that will not use protected. So yeah your right if you have a library that will only use public methods but I have yet to see one.